# Get Data of Sobject dynamically

Tags: apex, sobject

I'm trying to get a field value of a Sobject. for example for Case.

```
String cas = 'Case';
String caseid = '5003O000008QNUOQA4';
String query = 'SELECT Id,RecordTypeId,Answer_Type__c FROM ' + cas+  ' WHERE Id = \'' + caseid + '\'';
List<SObject> casList = Database.query(query);
System.debug(casList[0]); // Debug Result: Case:{Id=5003O000008QNUOQA4, RecordTypeId=0121v000000X31eAAC, Answer_Type__c=Qst17}
System.debug(casList[0].Id); //Debug Result: 5003O000008QNUOQA4
```

But `System.debug(casList[0].Answer_Type__c);` give me an error :

> Variable does not exist: Answer_Type__c.

And also `System.debug(casList[0].RecordTypeId);` give me the same error :

> Variable does not exist: RecordTypeId.

I guess I cant run in because Sobject as a class doesn't have the fields, but how can I get this data?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [SObject Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get), you can leverage `get()` where the single input parameter is the field API name you are looking to retrieve a value within.

```
String answerType = (String) casList[0].get('Answer_Type__c');
```

Comment: Thank you @TSmith